# Action Update Value works with Filter, but not with Filter In-DB

Tags: alteryx

In my workflow, a Date interface tool, with an Action to Update Value works with a Filter, but does not work with a Filter In-DB.  I would rather use the Filter In-DB, to avoid 100K+ records that I do not need being put into the Alteryx data stream.

The error message, reduced to relevant portion:

> There were errors: Filter In-DB (19): Error opening "WITH "Tool8_6ab5"
>   AS (Select ...connection select statement... ) SELECT * FROM
>   "Tool8_6ab5" WHERE "ReturnDate" = 2018-11-30": No Columns Returned.

2018-11-30 is the correct date, changed in the Filter In-DB to the value selected during Run As Analytic App, form the default date.   The same date returns records when used via Filter.   Let me know if any additional information would be helpful and I will edit into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a hint from BenMoss on the Alteryx Community, I discovered that for the Update Value action to work on the Filter In-DB, I needed to check, "Replace a specific string" (removing the default single quotes).

[image]